# The run time error by import python module

Tags: python-3.x, flask, import-module

I am trying to make correctly import the function "mmenu" from another module

**I got a run time error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path.../venv/src/routes.py", line 4, in <module>
    from venv.src.main_menu import mmenu
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'venv.src'
```

after Java this Python is a bit of a mystery to me :)

I have 2 files in the same "src" directory

**main_menu.py**

```
    def mmenu():
        menu = [{"name": "HOME", "url": "home"},
            {"name": "fooo", "url": "foo"},
            {"name": "bar", "url": "bar"},
            {"name": "CONTACT", "url": "contact"}]
        return menu
```

**routes.py**

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, session, redirect, abort
    from jinja2 import Template
    from flask.helpers import url_for
    from venv.src.main_menu import mmenu

    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    menu = mmenu
    
    @app.route("/")
    @app.route("/index")
    def index():
        # return "index"
        print("loaded" + url_for('index'))
        return render_template('index.html', title="Index page", menu=menu)

    # ...

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug=True)
```

*import was generated by IDE like:*

```
from venv.src.parts.main_menu import mmenu
```

Answer (score 0):

Your IDE (which IDE?) is likely misconfigured if it generates imports like that.

The `venv` itself, nor any `src` directory within them, shouldn't be within import paths.

You never mention you have a `parts/` package, but from the import I'll assume you do, and your structure is something like

```
venv/
  src/             # source root
    routes.py
    parts/         # parts package
      __init__.py  # (empty) init for parts package
      main_menu.py
```

With this structure, `main_menu` is importable as `parts.main_menu` from `routes.py` assuming you start the program with `python routes.py`.

If you have `__init__.py` files in `venv/` and/or `src/`, get rid of them; you don't want those directories to be assumed to be Python packages.

Comment: Thank You AKX! Exactly! The solution right in the order like:
```
venv/
  src/ 
```
instead
```
src/ 
 venv/  
```